# Parse a word document with PHPWord to html with formatting

Tags: php, phpword

I'm trying to parse word document and simulate the look from original file. Im using PHP word.

My code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
$path = '/pathtofiles';
$files = scandir($path);
unset($files[0]);
unset($files[1]);
$bold_style = ['' => '', 1 => ' font-weight:700; '];
function readDoc($document)
{
    global $bold_style;
    $phpWord = IOFactory::createReader('Word2007');
    $doc = $phpWord->load($document);
    $content = '';
    foreach ($doc->getSections() as $section) {
        foreach ($section->getElements() as $element) {
            if(get_class($element)=='PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\TextBreak')$content .= '<br>';
            if (method_exists($element, 'getElements')) {
                foreach ($element->getElements() as $k=>$childElement) {
                    if (method_exists($childElement, 'getText')) {
                        $font_size = $childElement->getFontStyle()->getSize();
                        $font_bold = $childElement->getFontStyle()->isBold();
                        $content .= '<span style="font-size:' . $font_size . '; ' . $bold_style[$font_bold] . '">' . $childElement->getText() . '</span> ';
                    } else if (method_exists($childElement, 'getContent')) {
                        $content .= $childElement->getContent() . ' ';
                    }
                }
            } else if (method_exists($element, 'getText')) {
                $content .= $element->getText() . ' ';
            }
            $content .= '<br>';
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Is there a better way to extract font styles, line breaks etc. from file ?

Comment: "Is there a better way" - Does the provided code work? If so, why change it? If it doesn't, what's wrong?